# Unable to query using peewee

Tags: python, peewee

This is the error:
peewee.OperationalError: no such table: stock

My folder structure is like this:

my_stocks -> data -> models.py

my_stocks -> data -> stock_data.db

my_stocks -> main.py

The models.py file contains:

```
from peewee import *
class Stock(Model):
    name = CharField()
    date = DateField()
    open = FloatField()
    high = FloatField()
    low = FloatField()
    close = FloatField()
    last = FloatField()
    volume = FloatField()
    turnover = FloatField()

    class Meta:
        database = SqliteDatabase('stock_data.db')
```

the main.py file contains:

```
from data.models import Stock

a =Stock.select().where(Stock.name == 'NSE/UPL')
for b in a:
    print b
```

Everytime I run main.py, a file called stock_data.db is created in my_stocks folder and 'peewee.OperationalError: no such table: stock' error shows up.

What am I doing wrong that a new db file is getting created even though I am just running a query and the db file has already been created in the models folder?

Comment: If I put main.py in the data folder, it runs perfectly.

Comment: Ok, got it fixed by putting a relative path for database name in models.py.
So now, database  = SqliteDatabase('data\stock_data.db')